# Cleared dropdown select2 using close button in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Good day, I'm confused is there any triggering point for this action in select2 dropdown? I think it is default in select2. The thing is whenever I click the close button under division dropdown the section dropdown should be cleared out. Any Idea is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select2:unselect` event of select2 plugin. This will get called when you unselect any option then inside this you can use `val(null).trigger('change')` to clear other select-box.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#one ,#second").select2({
  allowClear: true,
  placeholder: 'placeholder'
});
//when unselected..
$('#one').on('select2:unselect', function(e) {
  $('#second').val(null).trigger('change'); //clear other
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="one" class="form-control" style="width:150px">

  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option>purple</option>
</select>

<select id="second" class="form-control" style="width:150px">
  <option>orange</option>
  <option selected="selected">white</option>
  <option>purple</option>
</select>
```